# Bulk edit test steps in excel and then import to MTM?

Tags: excel, testing, microsoft-test-manager, manual-testing

Is it possible to Bulk edit test steps in excel and then import to MTM?

Ive found that i can create a query and then open that in excel to display the data i need, i can add on a column for "Steps" and i can enter in a step for single line but i cannot do multiple steps? Anyone had any luck with this?

Ive tried doing a multi line in the cell of excel but it just strips out formatting on publishing it and it keeps it on one Step line in MTM.

[Ive tried to put the steps on separate lines but it still imports as one step instead of two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elz2Y.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So i somewhat figured it out for myself.

Excel integration for bulk steps isnt integrated yet but you can do it through the web interface of VSTS.

You basically change the view of a query to grid mode and this enables you to see the tests in depth and add rows for copy & pasting.

Not a definitive solution but helps my cause!